The [dense_vector] field [vector] in doc [document with id '] has a different number of dimensions [384] than defined in the mapping [1000]
I am getting this error while trying to persist embeddings into elastic search. I am taking a file using post call in spring boot app and then using langchain4j elasticsearch embedding store trying to add embeddings.
Attaching code:
@PostMapping("/hellofile")
    public String fs(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

        String content = new String(file.getBytes());

        newAssistant = rag.newAssistant2(content);

        return "hello user! I am good to go you may ask questions now";
    }

This is how embedding are getting generated:
DocumentSplitter splitter = DocumentSplitters.recursive(300, 0);
        Document document = Document.from(file);

        List<TextSegment> segments = splitter.split(document);
        EmbeddingModel embeddingModel = new BgeSmallEnV15QuantizedEmbeddingModel();
        List<Embedding> embeddings = embeddingModel.embedAll(segments).content();

This is how embedding are getting store:
EmbeddingStore<TextSegment> embeddingStore = ElasticsearchEmbeddingStore.builder()
                .serverUrl("https://localhost:9200").userName("elastic").password("changeit")
                .indexName("indexsa").dimension(2)
                .build();
        embeddingStore.addAll(embeddings, segments);

I am expecting embeddigs to be store in db.

Which version of elasticsearch are you using? How do you specify 1000? Can you show the mapping for the index? The reason I am asking is 1) if 1000 is properly specified in mapping you will not be able to index any other records and 2) you seems to be using BAAI/bge-small-en-v1.5 which generates embeddings with 384 dimensions. So, the most likely reason is you don't actually specify 1000 in mapping and mapping autodetects 384 when you start indexing.

thanks mate i just change the code to ElasticsearchEmbeddingStore.builder().serverUrl("https://localhost:9200").userName("elastic")
.password("Jbyc8ck8+EVlg3mx=4u9").dimension(384).build(); @imotov

You should mark @dadoonet's answer then as a solution. He suggested it way before my comment.

You need to set the number of the exact dimensions. Example:
EmbeddingStore<TextSegment> embeddingStore = ElasticsearchEmbeddingStore.builder()
  .serverUrl("https://localhost:9200")
  .userName("elastic")
  .password("changeit")
  .indexName("indexsa")
  .dimension(384)
  .build();

